# Can UNIQUE keyword applied to a subquery?

Tags: sql, plsql, unique

I know that `UNIQUE` can be used for unique value on table creating.

I read in a database management book that

> When we apply UNIQUE to a subquery, the
>   resulting condition returns true if no row appears twice in the answer to the
>   subquery that is, there are no duplicates; in particular, it returns true if the
>   answer is empty.

I didn't see any query like that ,Is it possible?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using and what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to know if a result set returning by a query or a sub-query contains no duplicate records, or something else?

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I want to know that by using `distinct` instead of `unique` as in answer came, can I achieve to book's explanation about `unique`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNIQUE` is defined by *SQL92* Section 8.9: `<unique predicate> ::= UNIQUE <table subquery>` so it certainly exists but is not widely supported by vendors.

As an alternative you could use EXISTS with a HAVING COUNT.

Comment: I think you are right. Explanation of the [<unique predicate>](https://www.mariadb.com/kb/en/unique-predicate/)

Answer (score 1):

The UNIQUE constraint is typically used for defining table based constraints.

You should consider using `Select Distinct` for queries.

The following link provides details regarding the `Unique` and `Distinct` keywords.

http://psoug.org/definition/DISTINCT.htm

Comment: In Oracle (assuming it's Oracle, based on `plsql` tag) `distinct` and `unique` are synonyms.